# facebook open graph API name and namespace properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook Graph API to validate Facebook APPs, there was a property `canvas_name` which was returned by Graph API but Facebook replaced it with `namespace` and I started to use `namespace` instead of `canvas_name`.  As the Facebook API documentation says we have removed the canvas name with namespace.
The issue is that when I call the Graph API it sometimes returns `namespace` and sometimes only `name` it is confusing to decide which property to use.

Here are two different Facebook APPs I am validating through Graph API and getting different properties.

Which property should I use? `name` or `namespace`?

**http://graph.facebook.com/173782752713273**

```
{
   "id": "173782752713273",
   "name": "fbfarooqtv",  
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=173782752713273",    
   "namespace": "fbfarooqtv",    
   "icon_url": "http://photos-g.ak.fbcdn.net/photos-ak-snc7/v85006/137/173782752713273/app_2_173782752713273_9103.gif",    
   "logo_url": "http://photos-g.ak.fbcdn.net/photos-ak-snc7/v85006/137/173782752713273/app_1_173782752713273_8525.gif",    
   "weekly_active_users": "1",    
   "monthly_active_users": "2"    
}
```

and other returns

**http://graph.facebook.com/342927909107736**

```
{  
   "id": "342927909107736",
   "name": "Ticketveri",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=342927909107736",
   "icon_url": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yT/r/4QVMqOjUhcd.gif?_fbgz=1",
   "logo_url": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/y_/r/9myDd8iyu0B.gif?_fbgz=1"
}
```

**Thanks all of you have given answers**,
 I have accomplished my above task using appId, if anyone do not specify namespace for facebook app they can navigate to there app using appId like this
 `http://apps.facebook.com/173782752713273`

and if one specify the namespace then one can navigate to there app using appId and namespace too, as
 `http://apps.facebook.com/342927909107736` 
and `http://apps.facebook.com/fbfarooqtv`.
and I was validating facebook app from referrer of page, now I have added the fall back on namespace if any app do not have namespace then I takes the appId from referrer and validates it by calling graph API which returns the information about app if it exists. as bellow

```
http://graph.facebook.com/173782752713273
```

Comment: thanks all of you have given answers, I have accomplished my above task using appId, if anyone do not specify namespace for facebook app they can navigate to there app using appId link this http://apps.facebook.com/342927909107736   I am validating facebook app from referrer of page

Comment: would you know why sometimes it just returns false and other times the object described above?

Answer (score 5):

I think you should use "name" instead of "namespace".

The reason is that "name" corresponds to the "App Display Name" and "namespace" corresponds to "App Namespace" property in the App Settings of the application.

As "App Display Name" property is mandatory therefore it is guaranteed that you always get the value in "name" on the other hand the "App Namespace" property is optional therefore you will only get the value of namespace if it is set in APP settings.

[image]

Comment: I could not use name instead of namespace because I redirects the user to FB App after getting the namespace form graph  API

Comment: I think you will have to handle it, because it don't seems to be a good idea to navigate to page, which does not exists.

Answer (score 2):

The value you choose may depend on what you mean by "validating" apps. Where I work we have two "apps." One is a Windows desktop application, it doesn't require a namespace and has none. Our other "app" is a "Facebook app" that runs inside a Facebook canvas page in a web browser this does require a namespace and it has one.

Again, depending on what you are doing to "validate" the app will probably determine which of these values you need. For example if you want to navigate a browser to an "app" that runs in a Facebook canvas you will need to construct a URL like: "apps.facebook.com/app_namespace_here".

I'm not sure how you would validate a desktop app (or a mobile app).

Comment: For validating user  I ask for appID  when user give me his appId I call the graph API to validate the appId  like that "graph.facebook.com/1234567890" on correct appId graph API returns the name, namespace basic  info etc. 


But issue is that sometimes graph API returns the namespace sometimes not. and I could not use name instead of namespace because I redirects the user to FB App after getting the namespace form graph  API

Comment: The graph API response does not always include a namespace because not all applications are required to have one. A desktop application or website that access Facebook using the api will not have a namespace. No namespace means the app is not a Facebook canvas app and you can't navigate a browser to it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question right, you wonder under what conditions a request to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_APP_ID
```

results in a JSON response with a field called namespace, and under what conditions the namespace field is not included.

All apps have a name which is set when you create the app. The name field will always be returned when you issue the above request.

Apps don't have to have a namespace. It doesn't have to be specified when you create the app (although you can but it's not compulsory). If you create an app without a namespace, the request above will return a JSON reponse without a namespace.

In order words the most likely reason why app two in your example doesn't return a namespace is that it hasn't been specified on the app's setting page on Facebook Developers.

So, net, you can use either name or namespace for validation but if you use namespace you have to check it really has been added to the app settings.